# Extract links from a web page & write to console in Visual studios VB

Tags: visual-studio-2012, html-content-extraction

I am creating a web application with VS 2012 Express for web using VB. When a user types in a url, I want the page to return a list of all the links and text input boxes on the page that could be clicked on and taken to that page or to fill in the input box. I do not want the url visible.

For instance: if I type a url in the address bar and hit enter, a new window would appear only showing the links such as menu items or text unput boxes in the following format:

Link: [About Us](http://mypage.com)
[Text Input Box](http://mypage.com)

It would not show: (the actual html code- completed)

'a href="http://mypage.com">About Us'

Answer (score 0):

Use a WebBroswer control. Navigate to a page. Then WebBroswer1.Document.Links will have all the links in the page.